# How to instantiate a class from an internal method using @classmethod? [e.g. pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples()]

Tags: python, class, object, decorator, class-method

I feel like I may have butchered the phrasing for this but I am trying to instantiate a class from an internal method.  For example, in `pandas` there is the `MultiIndex` object which can either be instantiated by (A) `MultiIndex(*args)` or by (B) `MultiIndex.from_tuples(*args)` [or other `.from_` methods].  I'm trying to do the latter.

```
class ExampleClass(object):
    def __init__(self, name=None, data_1=None, data_2=None):
        self.name = name
        self.data_1 = data_1
        self.data_2 = data_2
    def from_custom(self, t, name=None):
        self.data_1 = np.sin(t)
        self.data_2 = np.cos(t)
        self.name = name
        return self

t = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi)
r_sin = np.sin(t)
r_cos = np.cos(t)
obj_A = ExampleClass(name="test", data_1=r_sin, data_2=r_cos)
obj_B = ExampleClass.from_custom(t, name="test")
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
# <ipython-input-12-26ccb0eee5a1> in <module>
#      14 obj_A = ExampleClass(name="test", data_1=r_sin, data_2=r_cos)
#      15 
# ---> 16 obj_B = ExampleClass.from_custom(t)

# TypeError: from_custom() missing 1 required positional argument: 't'
```

I looked at the source code for `pd.MultiIndex` via `??pd.MultiIndex` and noticed there was a `@classmethod` decorator.  I added the decorator and now it works.

```
class ExampleClass(object):
    def __init__(self, name=None, data_1=None, data_2=None):
        self.name = name
        self.data_1 = data_1
        self.data_2 = data_2
    @classmethod
    def from_custom(self, t, name=None):
        self.data_1 = np.sin(t)
        self.data_2 = np.cos(t)
        self.name = name
        return self

t = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi)
r_sin = np.sin(t)
r_cos = np.cos(t)
obj_A = ExampleClass(name="test", data_1=r_sin, data_2=r_cos)
obj_B = ExampleClass.from_custom(t, name="test")
print(obj_B.name, obj_B.data_1[:5], obj_B.data_2[:5], sep="\n")
# test
# [0.         0.12787716 0.25365458 0.375267   0.49071755]
# [1.         0.99179001 0.96729486 0.92691676 0.8713187 ]
```

Am I doing this correctly? I have never used `@classmethod` or `@staticmethod` before and I'm not entirely sure what they do after reading the documentation.

**Is this a/the correct way to instantiate an object from an internal method?**

EDIT: In response to the comment below:

```
class ExampleClass(object):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for k,v in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, k,v)
    @classmethod
    def from_custom(cls, t, name=None):
        data_1 = np.sin(t) * np.random.random()
        data_2 = np.cos(t) * np.random.random()
        name = name
        return cls(name=name, data_1=data_1, data_2=data_2)

t = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi)
r_sin = np.sin(t)
r_cos = np.cos(t)

np.random.seed(0)
obj_A = ExampleClass(name="test_A", data_1=r_sin, data_2=r_cos)
obj_B = ExampleClass.from_custom(t, name="test_B")
obj_C = ExampleClass.from_custom(t, name="test_C")

for obj in [obj_A, obj_B, obj_C]:
    print(obj.name, obj.data_1[:5], obj.data_2[:5], "\n", sep="\n")
# test_A
# [0.         0.12787716 0.25365458 0.375267   0.49071755]
# [1.         0.99179001 0.96729486 0.92691676 0.8713187 ]


# test_B
# [0.         0.07018071 0.13920906 0.2059516  0.26931242]
# [0.71518937 0.70931767 0.691799   0.66292101 0.62315787]


# test_C
# [0.         0.07707967 0.15289369 0.22619721 0.29578657]
# [0.54488318 0.5404097  0.5270627  0.50506135 0.47476691]
```

Comment: No, this is not correct. For a classmethod, the first argument, i.e. `self` is *the class* (so conventionally, you use `cls` as the name fo the parameter), so this doesn't work, because you are simply setting *class variables without instantiating anything*. I.e. `self` is equal to  `ExampleClass ` in the classmethod. Instead, do something like `instance = self()` (or better yet, using a more clear name, `instance = cls()`, then do your customized initialization on `instance` and return `instance`

Comment: Sorry this is going over my head a bit can you give an example in code?

Comment: Do you mean replacing self with cls for `from_custom`?

Comment: No, the actual name doesn't matter. The problem is that in a classmetgod the first argument is *the class object*, not an instance of the class. You are merely assigning class attributes, you never instantiate an instance, to do that you would need `self()`. Just ask yourself, *where* have you instantiates an instance in `from_custom`

Comment: Ok yea that makes sense w/ the name not mattering.  Where would I add `self()` or `cls()`?

Comment: *wherever you want to instantiate the object* in the classmethod. It will be the equivalent of doing `ExampleClass()`, in other words, `self` references `ExampleClass` in a classmethod. That's *what makes it a classmethod*. You are simply assigning `data1`, `data2` and `name` to `ExampleClass`. Try printing `ExampleClass.name` after you use your current version. or, try `obj_B is ExampleClass`

Comment: Is the edit I've made above the correct way to do it? It appears to be working